# What is a "macroplant"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a research paper that uses the word "macroplant", but I can't figure out what specifically that means, other than "big plant". Specifically what is a macroplant? Is it just something relatively big, like sunflower, saguaro, etc.? I can't find it in any dictionary and it isn't coming up in many searches. I can assume it means "big plant", but there must be a more nuanced definition.

Comment: I think the prefix 'macro' vs. 'micro' should clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a recently coined term. (not in MacMillan dictionary, nor Collins).

From the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/macroplant)

> (biology) Any plant that is large enough to be seen with the naked eye